# Django - for loop in one line

Tags: django, xml, for-loop

I'm exporting all product details from db to an XML file. One of the fields need to export is images. There are two fields where images should be exported. If there is one image (product table) should be exported to `item_image_link`. If there are more than one (ProductImage table) to `item_additional_image_link`.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(product_status=True).prefetch_related('images')

for product in products:
    item = ET.SubElement(channel, "item")
    g_item_id = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}id")).text = product.sku
    g_item_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}image_link")).text = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+products.image.url
    for image in product.images.all():
        g_item_additional_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}additional_image_link")).text = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+image.image.url
```

I successfully export the images per product in the respective field `item_additional_image_link` however they are shown in three different lines according to the number of images in db.

```
<item>
  <g:id>55555</g:id>
  <g:additional_image_link>http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photos/2021/12/20/K003-min.jpeg</g:additional_image_link>
  <g:additional_image_link>http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photos/2021/12/20/K009-min.jpeg</g:additional_image_link>
  <g:additional_image_link>http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photos/2021/12/20/image00024-min.jpeg</g:additional_image_link>
</item>
```

How can i make the three lines above in one, comma separated between each image? Something like:

```
<item>
  <g:id>55555</g:id>
  <g:additional_image_link>http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photos/2021/12/20/K003-min.jpeg, http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photos/2021/12/20/image00024-min.jpeg, http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photos/2021/12/20/K009-min.jpeg</g:additional_image_link>
</item>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the values before creating an `ET.SubElement(...)`

```
additional_image_links = ",".join([f"http://127.0.0.1:8000{x.image.url}" for x in product.images.all()])
if additional_image_links:
    g_item_additional_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}additional_image_link")).text = additional_image_links
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the string method `.join` on the multiple text fields to join them into one, then generate a single XML element. I'm guessing about ET...

```
g_item_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}image_link")
    ).text = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+products.image.url

texts = []
for image in product.images.all():
    texts.append( 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+image.image.url )

if texts: # don't generate an empty element
    g_item_additional_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}additional_image_link")
        ).text = ', '.join( texts)
```